# Debugging in autocad VBA ide is not displaying where the error is

Tags: vba, autocad, autocad-plugin

Whenever i am trying to debug or run the program and if it encounters error, the VBE (Autocad) doesn't display the line where the error is, unlike in other IDEs, it used to come at that line and highlight with yellow color. Also, the scroll doesn't work. I know i should install plugins but i am unable to help myself.
[image]

```
Option Explicit
    Sub Test()
    'Declarations
    'Opened Document
    Dim acDocu As AcadDocument
    Set acDocu = ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument

    'Select on screen
    Dim acSelectionSet As AcadSelectionSet
    Set acSelectionSet = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("SjjEffffT")
    acSelectionSet.SelectOnScreen

    'Manipulating in loops for finding group names having objects selected
    Dim entity As AcadEntity
    Dim entityhandle() As String
    Dim Grp As AcadGroup
    Dim groupname() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0
    Dim temp As Integer
    temp = 0
    Dim GrpEnt As AcadEntity
    Dim grpenthandle As String
    Dim entity_count As Integer
    'Dim entity_array As Variant
    entity_count = acSelectionSet.Count
    ReDim entityhandle(entity_count)
    ReDim groupname(entity_count)
    For Each entity In acSelectionSet
    'entity_array = entity
            entityhandle(i) = entity.Handle
            For Each Grp In ThisDrawing.groups
                   For Each GrpEnt In Grp
                   grpenthandle = GrpEnt.Handle
                   If entityhandle(i) = grpenthandle Then
                        If temp = 0 Then
                            groupname(j) = Grp.Name
                            Debug.Print "Group in selection:" & groupname(j)
                            j = j + 1
                        End If

                   End If
              temp = temp + 1
            Next
            temp = 0
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

   'Copying the objects and pasting into new drawing
   Dim acDocto As AcadDocument
   Dim file_name As String
   'file_name = InputBox("Enter the file name along with full path and extension")
   file_name = "D:\PI_Tool_files_3223\D00440023new.DWG"
   Set acDocto = Documents.Open(file_name)
   Dim acObject As AcadObject
   Dim retvalue As Variant
   retvalue = acDocu.CopyObjects(entityhandle, acDocto.ModelSpace)

   acSelectionSet.Delete
   End Sub
```

The code is written above. But i think the problem is with the add-in as i can't debug.

Comment: Without the code, any answer is a stab in the dark.

Comment: @Gareth Hey, my main problem is to debug, as i am unable to get the exact line, where it shows the error. may be because of plugin. don't know!

Comment: this happens because the VBA engine cannot find the object & method on the library, so when it tries to run the method, it throws the error. That's why you cannot see the line where it happens. For instance, you may create another sub and call you test() routine.

Comment: > scroll doesn't work. The VBA IDE has not changed since 1998. At this time, scroll wheel just began to gain some traction.

Comment: You could set a breakpoint at your very first line, and then traverse your code step by step.

Comment: Can you load the code into a module, instead of "ThisDrawing", then debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA IDE is pretty old (1998) and it has limited debugging abilities. You should stop using this, it's an obsolete technology, not actively supported by Microsoft/Autodesk anymore.

For some errors, it is not able to locate the line where the error occurred, and you're left with obscure error codes and useless messages.

Comment: What IDE should he use instead?

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x40c). The Community Edition is free for individuals, small organizations, learning environment, academic research and open source projects. Please read the [license terms](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550) to see if it fits to your usage. You can read this [tutorial](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=18162650&siteID=123112) to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the first possible line? (Set acDocu = ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument)
Then step through to see the offending object/property/method.
It doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the code into a module, instead of "ThisDrawing", then debug?

Comment: I have added the comment for you. You can delete the post.

Comment: Answers are used for complete answers only! It is better to comment. Sadly, you don't have rep.

Comment: Nice that you understood. Answer some good questions, you'll get to 50 in no time :)